# positive definiteness of an inner product in the polynomial space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

As an exercise I need to demonstrate that $\langle a,b\rangle = \int^{1}_{-1}f(t)g(t)dt$ is a valid inner product in the polynomial space in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm having big troubles with the demonstration of positive definiteness. I've noticed that $\langle a,a\rangle$ is a polynomial with an odd degree evaluated from -1 to 1, but I cannot conclude.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: $<a, a>$ is the integral of a non-negative function and must be non-negative.

Comment: @Paul but f and g are random polynomials and therefore can assume negative values

Comment: But positive definiteness is concerned with the value of $<a, a>$ not $<a, b>$.

Comment: @Paul okay it does make a lot of sense, but how do I prove it formally?